# Getting Data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using Firebase to retrieve data from firestore, And this is working fine, But now in order to save money and resources I am using a limit of 40 items, so only 40 items come from firebase, but now when the user reaches the end of the list i want the user to be able to get the next 40 items from the firebase data base. And that is what i dont know how to do. To get the next 40 items without having to read the whole 80 items from firebase..

This is my code:

```
getCountryItems() async{
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await userCountry
      .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
      .limit(40) //getting only 40 items
      //.orderBy('likesCount', descending: true)
      .getDocuments();

      List<Items> countryPosts = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Items.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
      setState(() {
        this.countryPosts = countryPosts;
      });
     }
```

So that is what is getting the First 40 items now i want to get the 40 items after this only after a button is pressed:

```
FlatButton(
 onPressed: (){}//funtion to get the next 40 items 
);
```

Comment: onPressed: async() {await getCountryItems() ... }

Comment: this would get the 1st 40 items again

Comment: .where("timestamp", ">", lastTimestampAt40)

Comment: also .startAfter(40)

Comment: can you please type all this properly in one code

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors
Use startAfter to move the cursor to desired position

```js
getCountryItems(paginateAt = 0) async{
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await userCountry
      .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
      .startAfter(paginateAt)
      .limit(40) //getting only 40 items
      //.orderBy('likesCount', descending: true)
      .getDocuments();

      List<Items> countryPosts = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Items.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
      setState(() {
        this.countryPosts = countryPosts;
      });
     }

FlatButton(
 onPressed: (){
   getCountryItems(this.countryPosts.last)
 }//funtion to get the next 40 items 
);
```